# Vega-Lite: How to use slider value in transform calculation

Tags: vega, vega-lite

How do I use the value of a slider in the transform?

This [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/sequence_line_fold) from vega online editor plots a sine and cosine wave.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Plots two functions using a generated sequence.",
  "width": 300,
  "height": 150,
  "data": {
    "sequence": {
      "start": 0,
      "stop": 12.7,
      "step": 0.1,
      "as": "x"
    }
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "sin(datum.x)",
      "as": "sin(x)"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "cos(datum.x)",
      "as": "cos(x)"
    },
    {
      "fold": ["sin(x)", "cos(x)"]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "field": "x"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "key",
      "type": "nominal",
      "title": null
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to add two sliders and use their values in the calculation. I can define sliders using:

```
  "selection" : {
    "amp" : {
      "type" : "single",
      "fields" : ["sin", "cos"],
      "bind": {
        "sin": { "input" : "range", "min": 0.0, "max": 10.0, "step": 0.1},
        "cos": { "input" : "range", "min": 0.0, "max": 10.0, "step": 0.1}
      }
    }
  },
```

How do I access the slider values to use in the calculations? Something like

```
    {
      "calculate": "amp.sin * sin(datum.x)",
      "as": "sin(x)"
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in exactly the way you wrote in your question. Additionally, adding an initial value will make the selections valid before you interact with them.

Here is a full example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AAVBbTBAAEmAO5tTAMwayoOuWYYQassqaSmycWXHUkTDhlUwg4AEcGPyg4SkUQCxplejQAZgAGDKV4GjIsNABGAFZslSCUVFBwqJi4NGrMJHVMNDKITDYcIoAmSgB2JQ64btQMykKlJAg0EAAPEABfRaVMQNkIGzZ1BDQAbVAoJEEoBkEg+vQkBBxKN1lTACow9wAKZSCGBEo5gEoE6aze6vP5LBSHY6nc7BWbXW5QNhmZ4IiDvT7fUFTGboFEg-4rUBbQTKfYgYGYkC40EAXUW1KUyHUAGtZsJ-AkYmxlO4yA15nzMABPHCXEBRJCyHRNHSkBI2GhwYmzBYrECCvnyxUk9DEY7RBJCkWzcWSuhBGiy1UIozqDUKpXoJlwdWrYWi2RsBDuY4GuiCS6yM6CZZDRVwRy6PlwgVuoE8-1y+3KbF7MnuBIokD0kDuOh8+5FJSZ1CFVVMdza6rpqo52Q4BitdDrXwJL16MrIBYl9rBUbjUtFxF89z1xsgZv1BnVjtILuFHsjNoTZYroA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Plots two functions using a generated sequence.",
  "width": 300,
  "height": 150,
  "data": {"sequence": {"start": 0, "stop": 12.7, "step": 0.1, "as": "x"}},
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "amp.sin * sin(datum.x)", "as": "sin(x)"},
    {"calculate": "amp.cos * cos(datum.x)", "as": "cos(x)"},
    {"fold": ["sin(x)", "cos(x)"]}
  ],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "x"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal", "title": null}
  },
  "selection": {
    "amp": {
      "type": "single",
      "fields": ["sin", "cos"],
      "init": {"sin": 1, "cos": 1},
      "bind": {
        "sin": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 10, "step": 0.1},
        "cos": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 10, "step": 0.1}
      }
    }
  }
}
```